# Text go to the line without reason

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to learn react-native following the development of a simple app with a tutorial.

It is supposed to show correctly on the same line the title and the average vote of a movie, but the vote always goes to the line.

I try to reduce the title size, reduce the Vote size and to padding the vote. But none of this works, it's always going to the line.

So I copied the code from the course and it's doing it again.

I try to understand why and not to go on with misunderstood part of the course.

Thank you for your help.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfcOh.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4OIx.jpg

```
View style={styles.content_container}>
          <View style={styles.header_container}>
            <Text style={styles.title_text}>{film.title}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.vote_text}>{film.vote_average}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.description_container}>
            <Text style={styles.description_text} numberOfLines={6}>{film.overview}</Text>
            {/* La propriété numberOfLines permet de couper un texte si celui-ci est trop long, il suffit de définir un nombre maximum de ligne */}
          </View>
          <View style={styles.date_container}>
            <Text style={styles.date_text}>Sorti le {film.release_date}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>

...


main_container: {
    height: 190,
    flexDirection: 'row'
  },
  image: {
    width: 120,
    height: 180,
    margin: 5,
    backgroundColor: 'gray'
  },
  content_container: {
    flex: 1,
    margin: 5
  },
  header_container: {
    flex: 3,
    flexDirection: 'row'
  },
  title_text: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 20,
    flex: 1,
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    paddingRight: 5
  },
  vote_text: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 26,
    color: '#666666',

  },
  description_container: {
    flex: 7
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was adding `flex: .5` to both `title-text` and `vote-text`

Comment: Thank you for answer. 
It is not working. Same result.

Comment: ... remove flex:1 from `title-text`?

Comment: The vote going under the title (over description) and on two lines (again).
It's strange

Comment: Okay how about giving` title-text` and `vote-text` `flex: .5`

Comment: Working ! Perfect is 0.8 and 0.2

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Nice.  Thanks Lindraks.  Was it all of those three things?  If so I'll edit my answer.

Comment: No, just the last one :)